# Cassandra: Undo transaction in cassandra

Tags: spring-mvc, cassandra, hector

I am using Cassandra in spring MVC. How can i undo Cassandra transaction in hector if any exception occurs. e.g if i am inserting data in two column family and one gets failed then it should delete the data inserted in other CF.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like what you want is an [atomic batch](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/atomic-batches-in-cassandra-1-2), which is available using CQL as of 1.2.  Keep in mind that there's some overhead in this.  If you're using atomic batches there's no manual commit or rollback, as Cassandra handles this implicitly.

Comment: How is this possible without CQL

Comment: The Thrift-based `atomic_batch_mutate` is supported, however it [doesn't appear to be supported](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/hector-users/tfFDITIubos/3qhyn97fWtAJ) in Hector.  If your transaction updates multiple columns in a single row, a standard `batch_mutate` will do the job.  But from your question I gather this isn't the case.

Comment: Hi @rs_atl, I know this is old answer, but still seems to be pretty useful to me. By overhead of batch operation, I think you are referring to the load on co-ordinator node when tonnes of such batch operations run in parallel. One question here - can we not use asynchronous execution? Is there any way to custom handle atomicity? May be in the exception block, rollback the committed transactions?